# How to find exactly which note you hit

Tags: voice

Is there any computer program that measures the hertz of a vocal clip?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/61633/voice-meter-software/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a tuner? If you already have some kind of DAW software it might have one built in. If you have an iOS or Android device there are all kinds of tuner apps available.

Answer (score 0):

There are many pitch tuner softwares out there that can help you do that(monitoring frequency)... One that suits your need is a vst by the name GTune by GVST. Check it out at www.GVST.co.uk
Oh... And it's free[image: I'm using it in FL Studio 12] Enjoy